# Xcode Project Issue when using xcode project started in other xcode on other mac

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode-project

I am trying to use xcode project on other xcode. When i open the project all works fine til open main.storyboard. On open the storyboard i cannot see the editor and only leave one error. Can some one help me please, Im stuck  :)))

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Unknown model format” sounds like your Core Data model is corrupt or that parts of it are missing. If the project still works on the original Mac, something may have gone wrong when copying it to the new Mac. You should get a new copy and verify that all files are copied without changes.

Comment: Thank you for answer Tom! I will tell you something when i fix it